# R ggvis: Second x-axis with different labels

Tags: r, ggvis

I would like to add a second x-axis in ggvis using different labels than the first x-axis.

Here is an example:

```
tt <- data.frame(x = c(1:30), y = c(1:30), z = rep(c("one", "two", "three"), 10))
xsel <- tt$x[tt$x %% 5 == 1]
xsellabels <- tt$z[tt$x %in% xsel]

tt %>%
  ggvis(~x, ~y) %>%
  layer_lines() %>%
  add_axis("x") %>%
 add_axis("x", title = "Axis2",
       values = xsel,
       orient = "top",
       properties = axis_props(grid = list(stroke = "blue")))
```

This plot already has both x-axes and the gridlines are positioned correctly. However, I would like to change the labels of the axis on the top but not the ones of the axis on the bottom. The correct labels for the top axis are stored in xsellabels (extracted from tt$z). Thus, instead of the labels 1, 6, 11, 16, 21, 26, I would like to get the labels "one", "three", "two", "one", "three", "two".

Thanks for any ideas how to achieve this!

Comment: this is possible, but not with same labels for multiple ticks.